# is it ok that multi threads write to different variables of a shared object in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

so this shared object is like this(just for demo, not a working one):

```
class Shared{
int var1;
int var2;

public:
    void setter1(int var){
        var1=var;
    }

    void setter2(int var){
        var2=var;
    }

}
```

And can `thread1` do `shared->setter1(3)` while `thread2` do `shared->setter2(2)` at the same time without any race condition or problems?

Comment: Which thread reads the data? You should add thread safety on this data object if you ever want to read the data while the threads are still active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can access individual subobjects of `Shared` object in two independent threads without synchronization, that will not be a race condition. The laymen explanation is given on the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races), here is the partial quote:

> Different threads of execution are always allowed to access (read and
>   modify) different memory locations concurrently, with no interference
>   and no synchronization requirements.

However, watch out for [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads)! Your code seems to be prone to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sharing in your example. When you're talking about what is shared between threads, then the only thing that matters is memory location.

If you have a variable of type `Shared s;`, then `s.var1` and `s.var2` are two different memory locations. If `s.var1` is only ever accessed by one thread, and `s.var2` is only ever accessed by some other thread, then neither of those memory locations is shared.

But do watch out for the *false* sharing that @SergeyA warned you about. It won't impact the *correctness* of your program, but it could impact the performance.